# PHP website with RESTful API using Django. Possible? Good Idea?

Tags: php, django, api, restful-authentication, rest

I have an existing website written in PHP. I would like to add a REST API.  I like how easy creating a RESTful API was using Django.  Are there any CONS for using Django for the sole purpose of creating an API on a PHP powered website?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of cons:

- your codebase will be larger
- every change in the data model on one side must be done on the other side aswell
- it will require more resources from your server
- you have 2 systems to maintain

But for the rest, I can see why it would be easier to do this with Django than it would be to do with a plain PHP API. I have my doubts that there are no PHP libraries available to do something similar though.

Comment: Can you provide one example for php with django rest api. If possible, share any tutorial

Comment: @AKHILMATHEW I would recommend using `django-rest-swagger` to generate a swagger definition and generate the php client from there. After that you're pretty much done

Answer (score 0):

I love Django, but I'm not sure that it would benefit you here. Maybe I don't completely understand how you plan to use it, but it seems like if you already have your data access and logic done in PHP then you would have to re-code that in Python in order to leverage Django.

If what you really want is clean urls and simple url mapping then you could probably use [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) or [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/). That way you don't need to rewrite your existing code in Python or having the same code in 2 different languages.